# How to install Kubeflow cli

Tags: kubeflow, mlops

I am playing with Kubeflow's containerized python components. As per the below doc, we can push component to container registry by using "target_image" flag in the definition and running the following command: "kfp component build .............".

https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2/components/containerized-python-components/#3-build-the-component

I am having a hard time figuring out how to install Kubeflow cli. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to the documentation or an alternative way to build the component.

The below link refers to how to use Kubeflow cli but there is no mention of how to install it.
https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0b16/source/cli.html#kfp

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really about Kubeflow Pipelines, not Kubeflow. Pipelines is part of the Kubeflow project, but it's not Kubeflow itself. To install: `pip install --pre kfp` (from the [front page of the docs](https://kubeflow-pipelines.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)).